Gzip compression not working in spring boot project
I am trying to implement gzip compression in my spring boot project(v2.7.12).
I have added below in application.properties file.
server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
        min-response-size: 10
        mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
        compression-level: 6

Now once i hit the API and adding request header as Accept-Encoding: gzip , I don't get back Content-Encoding: gzip back in the response header.

Your configuration looks correct. See spring boot class as reference (compression-level doesn't seems to do anything)
Here is a list of thing you can check

You are running your app with embedded web server (java -jar). This does not work if you deploy your app as war on app server. I am assuming your are using tomcat embedded for the next points
On app bootstrap, put a breakpoint here and check that your configuration are properly applied
Accept-Encoding request header needs to include gzip, which looks like you did
Content-type response header needs to be one of the application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain. Please check you are sending proper Accept request header also.
Response size needs to be greater than min-response-size (10 bytes here)
Response header does not contains ETAG
If none of the above gives the answer. Put a breakpoint in org.apache.coyote.CompressionConfig#useCompression and figure out why it respond false.

Hope this helps

ETAG is present in the response header

There you have the reason. If you have ETAG, gzip filter does not work. There is way, if you cant make the ETAG starts with "W/", it indicate that it isn't a strong ETAG.
https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/coyote/CompressionConfig.java#L234

I dont understand one point.When my API returns 890 Bytes,i can see Content-Type header returned and no ETAG. But when my API returns 12 KB of response,it does not have Content Type header but has ETAG. Not sure why bigger response size do not work and smaller ones work.

Not having content type does not sounds right. You need to check the code that generate the ETAG on your endpoint, something does not feel right about that. You will also find the answer as to why sometimes you have etags, and sometimes not

Just debugged.ETag is generated for >=200 and <300 response statuses. The 890 Bytes API's response is a 400 Bad request ,hence did not generate an ETag,and 12 KB API's response was a 200 status code,so it generated an ETag.

Feel free to mark the question as answered if it was helpful
